# C++: unable to read the stuff in side an array

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I set up an array inside a class and I store some variables inside, but when I try to read those variables inside the array, it always prints out some blank and empty things.

this is my header file:

```
class animal{
private:
    string name;
    int age;
    int state;
    double income;
    string health;

};

class seaLion: public animal{
private:
    string name;
    int state;
    int age_sl;
    string health;
    seaLion *c;

public:
    seaLion();
    seaLion(string name, int age);
    ~seaLion();
    seaLion(const seaLion& copy);
    seaLion &operator = (const seaLion& copy);
    void new_sl(seaLion *c,int num);
    void cal_income(seaLion *,double);
};
```

this is my cpp file

```
// constructor and big3 also include
// this function is trying to create and store new sea lion in the sea lion class.
void seaLion::new_sl(seaLion *c, int num) {
    //c = new seaLion[num_sl];
    for(int i = num_sl-num; i < num_sl; i++) {
        c[i].name = "Sea Lion";
        c[i].age_sl = 48;
        c[i].state = 1; //state 1 for adult
        c[i].health = "health";
        cout << c[i].name << endl;
    }
}

// this function is using to calculate the revenue, but it always prints out nothing.
void seaLion::cal_income(seaLion *c, double income) {
    int inf, adu;
    for(int i = 0; i < num_sl; i++){
        cout << c[i].name << endl;
        if(c[i].age_sl < 6 && c[i].age_sl >= 0){
            inf += 1400;
        }
        if(c[i].age_sl > 6)  {
            adu += 700;
        }
    }
    income = adu + inf;
}
```

Comment: Change private to protected for animal.

Comment: *but it always prints out zero* - what value ? that function prints a name; that's it. Second, `income = ...` is pointless in `cal_income`, since it is passed by value so all you're doing is changing the value of a local variable. It will never see the light of day outside that member function. Third, the `+=` operators in that function are acting on *indeterminate* values, since you never initialized *anything* (not that it means anything, since none of those values are ever taken beyond that member, making it effectively an expensive way to print names, and then return).

Comment: May I ask why aren't you using a `vector` of `seaLion` instead? Where is `num_sl` declared and initialized? Also, do you realize that you have members of the derived class shadowing members of the base class with the same name?

Answer (score 0):

If you do some searching into "C++ inheritance", you can find [this page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_inheritance.htm) for instance:

> **Access Control and Inheritance**
>
> A derived class can access all the non-private members of its base class. Thus base-class members that should not be accessible to the member functions of derived classes should be declared private in the base class.
>
> We can summarize the different access types according to "who can access them" in the following way
>
> Access: - public - protected - private
>
> Same class - yes - yes - yes
>
> Derived classes - yes - yes - no
>
> Outside classes - yes - no - no

So `Sealion` cannot access the variables in `Animal`. However, you hide that by declaring local variables in `Sealion` with the same name.
If you'd make an object like `Animal* sl = new Sealion();` and write to `sl->name`, you're writing to the `name` in `Animal`. And if you try to access `name` within a `Sealion` member function, you're accessing `name` in `Sealion`... Those are different objects!

I suggest you start following a basic C++ tutorial or book, as there are some serious issues with your code. This is how I would do it in C++

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>

class Animal {
protected:
    std::string name{};
    int age{};
    int state{};
    double income{};
    std::string health{};
public:
    virtual ~Animal() {} // needed for inheritance
    virtual int CalculateIncome() = 0;
};

class Sealion final : public Animal { // final: cannot be derived from
public:
    int CalculateIncome() override { // a specific implementation for the sealion
        if (age >= 6) return 2100;
        if (age >= 0) return 1400;
        return 0;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Animal>> animals{}; // unique_ptr will handle object creation and destruction on heap
    animals.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Sealion>()); // add one animal: a sealion

    std::cout << "Total income: "
        << std::accumulate(std::cbegin(animals), std::cend(animals), 0, 
            [](int total, std::unique_ptr<Animal> const& animal) { return total + animal->CalculateIncome(); })
        << '\n';
}
```